# I can't test styles override by theme in mui

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, themes, react-testing-library

I created custom theme using mui

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const customTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
            borderRadius: '8px',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I would like to test whether component styles are overridden. I created tests for this purpose using react-testing-library

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/system';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { customTheme } from './theme/';

describe('Theme', () => {
  it('should render TextField with overridden styles', () => {
    //Arrange
    render(
      <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme }>
        <TextField data-testid='textField'></TextField>
      </ThemeProvider>,
    );

    //Act
    const element = document.querySelector('.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline');
    const styles = getComputedStyle(element);

    //Assert
    expect(styles.getPropertyValue('border-radius')).toBe('8px');
  });
});
```

But I received:
● Theme › should render TextField with overridden styles

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "8px"
Received: "inherit"

  19 |
  20 |     //Assert
> 21 |     expect(styles.getPropertyValue('border-radius')).toBe('8px');
     |                                                      ^
  22 |   });
```

I tried fetching the component using screen.getElementbyId and toHaveStyle, and using the debugger I checked that the styles are not overwritten.